# google analytics api node.js

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-api, jwt

I'm trying to call the google analytics api in node. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm getting 'path.replace is not a function' in node_modules/mime/mime.js, but I'm certain the problem is with my auth. (my log is not being hit btw)

```
const
  gapi      = require ("googleapis"),
  profileid = '000000000',
  key       = require ('./key.json'),
  email     = 'email@email.com',
  scopes    = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'],
  jwt       = new gapi.auth.JWT (email, key, null, scopes, null);

gapi.analytics ('v3').data.ga.get ({
  'auth': jwt,
  'ids': 'ga:' + profileid,
  'start-date': '30daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'today',
  'metrics': 'ga:pageviews'
}, function (err, result) {
  console.log (err, result);
});
```

UPDATE: I tried to use an API key instead like so. In this case my log does get hit. But I get a 'Login Required' error.

```
const
  gapi      = require ("googleapis"),
  API_KEY   = 'IzaSyDbIBVkt5kia3CJ3w2Y3-nsLHDpSruERkw';

gapi.analytics ('v3').data.ga.get ({
  'auth': API_KEY,
  'ids': 'ga:' + profileid,
  'start-date': '30daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'today',
  'metrics': 'ga:pageviews'
}, function (err, result) {
  console.log (err, results);
});
```

this oauth playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ leads me to believe you need a google analytics login and scope to get an authorization code. And with the authorization code you can get an access token. And once you have that you can simply make the request with parameters to get what you need. The problem is getting it in code.

The code snippets I've seen that involve getting the Authorization code do it in a way that has the user get it from a consent page (like here https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#retrieve-authorization-code), but I'm just trying to do a server to server app, and I'm not getting user data so I shouldn't need permission from a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing server-side requests you can go the jwt route and use the jwt json file that Google provides when you go through the "Server-Side" flow on [cloud.google.com/console](http://cloud.google.com/console). See [these docs](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#using-jwt-service-tokens) for the jwt explanation and [this sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/jwt.js) for a snippet. It uses the Google Drive API in the example but your question is focused on getting server-side auth to work.

The relevant changes I made to make it work:

```
var authClient = new google.auth.JWT(
'service-account-email@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
'CHANGE_THIS_TO_YOUR_JSON.json',
// Contents of private_key.pem if you want to load the pem file yourself
// (do not use the path parameter above if using this param)
'',
// Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single, space-delimited string
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],
// User to impersonate (leave empty if no impersonation needed)
'');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the first method to work with the following changes.

1. flipped the 2nd and 3rd arguments in the JWT function
2. passed in the private_key from the json file instead of the entire file
3. used the email from the json file instead of my google email
4. made new user in google analytics with the given email

   ```
   const
     gapi      = require ("googleapis"),
     profileid = '000000000',
     key       = require ('./key.json'),
     scopes    = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
     jwt       = new gapi.auth.JWT (key.client_email, null, key.private_key, scopes);

   jwt.authorize (function (err, response) {

     gapi.analytics ('v3').data.ga.get ({
       'auth': jwt,
       'ids': 'ga:' + profileid,
       'start-date': '30daysAgo',
       'end-date': 'today',
       'metrics': 'ga:pageviews'
     }, function (err, result) {
       console.log (err, result);
     });

   });
   ```